# Batch insert/update from one table to another within the Postgres database using Psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, cursor, psycopg2

I am inserting/updating 5 million rows into the target table from source table within Postgres, In order to run my update and insert queries I am using psycopg2 python package and doing something very plain as opening the connection and then opening the cursor ,and running

cursor.execute(update_query)

cursor.execute(insert_query)

It does work just fine .However from the documentation I understand that psycopg2 provides certain (execute_many, execute_batch) methods to reduce network roundtrip, can I take the advantage of these methods while updating, inserting the rows **within** the database as well ?

**Queries used :-**

**Update:-**

```
UPDATE target_tbl tgt
        set descr = stage.descr,
        prod_name = stage.prod_name,
        item_name = stage.item_name,
        url       = stage.url,
        col1_name = stage.col1_name,
        col2_name = stage.col2_name,
        col3_name = stage.col3_name,
        col4_name = stage.col4_name,
        col5_name = stage.col5_name,
        col6_name = stage.col6_name,
        col7_name = stage.col7_name,
        col8_name = stage.col8_name,
        flag      = stage.flag
    from tbl1 stage
    where 
    tgt.col1 = stage.col1
    and tgt.col2 = stage.col2
    and coalesce(tgt.col3, 'col3'::text) = coalesce(stage.col3, 'col3'::text)
    and coalesce(tgt.col4, 'col4'::text) = coalesce(stage.col4, 'col4'::text);
```

**Insert:-**

```
Insert into tgt
    select 
    stage.col1,
    stage.col2,
    stage.col3,
    stage.col4
    stage.prod_name,
    stage.item_name,
    stage.url,
    stage.col1_name,
    stage.col2_name,
    stage.col3_name,
    stage.col4_name,
    stage.col5_name,
    stage.col6_name,
    stage.col7_name,
    stage.col8_name,
    stage.flag
    from tbl1 stage
    where NOT EXISTS (
    select from tgt where
    tgt.col1 = stage.col1
    and tgt.col2 = stage.col2
    and coalesce(tgt.col3, 'col3'::text) = coalesce(stage.col3, 'col3'::text)
    and coalesce(tgt.col4, 'col4'::text) = coalesce(stage.col4, 'col4'::text)
    ) ;
```

Comment: What are your queries? Not sure why  something like `INSERT INTO some_table SELECT * FROM other_table` would not work?

Comment: @Adrian Klaver ,I am sorry my description in question was not clear,I just edited that,It does work .However my question is can execute_batch or execute_many can giev any performance boost if executed to move the data within the database.I may be wrong but as per my understanding,these postgres bulk methods are meant to reduce I/O involved in round trip during a network transfer .

Comment: You still haven't shown the queries you are currently using. If the `INSERT` query is similar to the one I posted, the `execute_batch/many` will make things slower as you would have multiple transactions instead of the one you have now.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver ,I have updated my question with the queries.

Comment: Then `execute_batch/many` will not be an improvement. Right now all you are sending across the network is the `SQL` commands, the work is being in a single transaction on the server. The batch commands would require you to send pull the data out of the server and then send it back, not efficient at all and not what they where designed for. See [execute_batch](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html?highlight=execute_batch#psycopg2.extras.execute_batch). They where meant for easing putting data in from external source.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Adrian Klaver for explanation. you cleared my confusion.